# I have all my posts in /source/_posts of Octopress, how do I deploy them to Github pages?

Tags: jekyll, octopress, github-pages

For some reason, my `gh-pages` remote is tracking the `_deploy` directory within `octopress/`.

So when I do a push within that folder, it pushes an empty blog install.

I have a ton of posts in `source/_posts`, but I want to deploy them to my `gh-pages` branch.

I tried `rake deploy` and that doesn't seem to do the trick. It still pushes an empty blog.

How do I get the posts from `source/_posts` to `_deploy`?

I am afraid to do it manually, for fear I may break something.

Comment: Have you get things done? I face the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the page first (thus populating your _deploy directory) via `rake generate` and then push those contents to the gh-pages branch via `rake deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

I have blogged a lot about Octopress. You might find answers here:
http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2012/06/04/creating-a-github-blog-using-octopress/